# how to remove unicodes from a dataset in pandas python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a dataset name rssfeeds  which as � � � , how to remove this unicodes and replace with its original values

my dataset:- 
[image]

please help me guys

Comment: Yeah i think it's `pandas.remove_unicode("weird symbol that looks like ? mark")`, but i might be wrong. Welcome to Stack Overflow- Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: These look like UTF-8 encoded  “fancy-quotes” and apostrophes to me.  Can you edit the question to include the code to read this data.

Comment: Please see the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) for information about how to diagnose and ask questions about unknown character codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use Series.str.decode() on the columns with the offending encoding,](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.decode.html#pandas.Series.str.decode) but I don't prefer this method if your can reread the data and have direct access to it.

You can use the `encoding='utf-8'` argument when you read the data and Pandas will try to work it out for you. Something like this assuming your data is in a csv and is UTF-8 encoded:

`df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", encoding="utf-8")`

Edit: you noted that your data is imported from a db, and `pandas.read_sql` does not have the `encoding` arg. As such I would suggest using my first suggestion, `Series.str.decode()`. You would use it like this on a column:

`df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].str.decode("encoding_name")`

If you encounter errors you can pass a kwarg `errors`, the default is `strict` but you can also `ignore`.

`df["column_name"] = df["column_name"].str.decode("encoding_name", errors="policy")`

Comment: I am importing it from mongodb so how can I use this

Comment: @RahulVarma I added an edit to address this. If the response addressed your original question then mark it as answered.

Comment: try his :- df.replace(['\d+', r'(?u)[^\w\s\?]+', '\s*$'], ['','',''], regex=True)